# -bash: psql: command not found. PostgreSQL post installation error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install postgres 9.5 on redhat linux (RHEL6). I have successfully installed PostgreSQL and it is starting and running when i run this script -> runpsql.sh but psql or psql -U postgres is not working, Why? I have set environment variables also.

[image: screen2]

Installation directories : /u02/PostgreSQL/9.5
Data directory : /u02/PostgreSQL/9.5/data

after that Environment variables are also set

PATH=/u02/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin:$PATH
export PATH

MANPATH=/u02/PostgreSQL/9.5/share/man:$MANPATH
export MANPATH

Also

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u02/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/sbin/ldconfig /u02/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib

Getting these errors:

[image: error_img1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your database and start it.

```
init.db -D [database directory]
pg_ctl -D [database directory] -Start
```

Comment: Please see the edit. Actually init.db and pg_ctl  not found.

Comment: I have installed 9.5. On RHEL path is ./usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/ Try looking around your install folders for these if the installation went correctly they will be in there. You can use find from a parent directory eg. find . -name "initdb"